# jQuery Mobile click event not firing?

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-mobile

I have tried to fix this all morning so please help me if you can.

I've got this code:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function(){
    var menuOpen;
    // Menu
    $('#menu-trigger').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('click!');
        if(menuOpen != true) {
            $('.ui-page-active').animate({
                'margin-left': '390px'
            }, 300, function(){
                menuOpen = true
            });
            return false;
        } else {
            $('.ui-page-active').animate({'margin-left': 0}, 300, function(){menuOpen = false});
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

My problem is that I never get the "**click!**" alert. After clicking on the element with the `id` `#menu-trigger`, nothing happens.

I have tried everything I can but still no result.

My code is inside a `script` tag, just below the jQuery Mobile script inclusion.

P.S.: Here is the HTML code fragment:

```
<header data-role="header" class="with-logo">
  <a href="#" id="#menu-trigger" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-left"><img src="images/menu-trigger-icon.png"></a>
  <h1><img src="images/logo.png"></h1>
</header><!-- /header -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the hash symbol from the anchor's id attritute value.

The anchor tag should be like:

```
<a href="#" id="menu-trigger" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-left">
```

and the event handler script should be like:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '#menu-trigger', function(e){
        // your code
    });
</script>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: O M G! I am an idiot :D Thanks so much for noticing! This is a fine example how a little stone could turn the car over :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

you should be binding the pageinit to a div that has `data-role = "page"`, not to document.

also depending on what your html looks like, you may be using 'on' on the wrong element.  it needs to be a parent element of the element you want to bind code to your click event.
so it is like

```
$('#someparent').on('click', yourfunctionasdefinedabove, '#menu-trigger');
```

(If menu-trigger is the parent, please ignore this second part)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! By parent do you mean the direct parent of the element or just any parent?

Comment: I am not sure I understand :( I have updated the question with the html segment I am using.